# Prevent caching of index.html but allow caching of scripts

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular2 app where I only want to force reload of the index.html page when the webpage is visited but I don't want to reload all the script files if they have already been downloaded.

Is this possible using a meta tag? e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Comment: By default JS is cached at first load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pragma meta, your index.html will not be cached but dependency may be cached anyway :

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```